# How to dynamically change a text when hovering an element with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have this in my HTML page :

```
<div class="hello">
  <img @mouseover="hover='A'" @mouseleave="hover=''" src="a.png" alt="A" />
  <img @mouseover="hover='B'" @mouseleave="hover=''" src="b.png" alt="B" />
  <br /><br />
  <span>{{ hover }}</span>
</div>
```

and this in my script :

```
var hello = new Vue({
  el: ".hello",
  data: {
      hover: ''
  }
});
```

But the text does not change when I hover an image. I tried with a `<span>` wrapping each image, but it does not work either.

What do I do?

Comment: Even if Neves' solution is correct, it is more or less what I already had done. The problem was caused by the `<div>` being wrapped in another `<div>`, to which a Vue object was applied. (I don't know if it's understandable, sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '.hello',
  data: {
    hover: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.5/vue.min.js"></script>
<div class="hello">
  <img @mouseover="hover='A'" @mouseleave="hover=''" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" alt="a">
  
  <img @mouseover="hover='B'" @mouseleave="hover=''" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2" alt="B">
  
  <br>
  
  <span>Hover: {{ hover }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It was exactly what I had done... except I was wrapping it in another `<div>` in order to apply a dynamic style with Vue.